# PHP json array manipulation

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON array like this:

```
{
   result:{
      customers:[
         {
            customer_id:16096,
            customer_name:"test@test.test",
            customer_login_name:"******",
            customer_login_pwd:"*****",
            customer_active:0,
            customer_register_date:"2018-07-20 10:48:22",
            customer_dashboard_email:"******",
            customer_dashboard_pwd:"******",
            used:"0.00",
            name:"Trial",
            price:0,
            bandwidth:1,
            start_date:"2018-07-20",
            end_date:"2018-07-27",
            package_is_active:1
         },
         {
            customer_id:16648,
            customer_name:"asd@asd.asd",
            customer_login_name:"******",
            customer_login_pwd:"********",
            customer_active:1,
            customer_register_date:"2018-08-08 17:24:16",
            customer_dashboard_email:"******@*******.com",
            customer_dashboard_pwd:"******",
            used:"0.00",
            name:"Trial",
            price:0,
            bandwidth:1,
            start_date:"2018-08-08",
            end_date:"2018-08-15",
            package_is_active:1
         },
         {
            customer_id:15271,
            customer_name:"MarioRossiTEST",
            customer_login_name:"mario@test.test",
            customer_login_pwd:"*****",
            customer_active:0,
            customer_register_date:"2018-06-22 11:36:42",
            customer_dashboard_email:"*****@******.com",
            customer_dashboard_pwd:"*******",
            used:"0.00",
            name:"Trial",
            price:0,
            bandwidth:1,
            start_date:"2018-06-22",
            end_date:"2018-06-30",
            package_is_active:0
         },
      ]
   }
}
```

Now in PHP i would like to provide the "customer_name" and retreive the "customer_id" of the same customer.

For example i provide "test@test.test" and i would like to get "16096".
Any way i could do this?

Comment: [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)? This question is Googleable, even if you just Googled '*json php*' you would have found your answer. In the future you should do some research and consider taking the [tour].

Comment: Kindly post what you have tried as in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: After decoding the JSON array to PHP:

If you are doing this very often, I would suggest for looping through the array and creating a dictionary with the "customer_name" value as the key and the "customer_id", "customer_login_name", etc. in a dictionary that's the value to the "customer_name" key.

```
$customers_dic = {
     "test@test.test"=> {
        customer_id => 16096,
        customer_login_name => "******",
        customer_login_pwd =>"*****",
        customer_active => 0,
        customer_register_date => "2018-07-20 10:48:22",
        customer_dashboard_email => "******",
        customer_dashboard_pwd => "******",
        used => "0.00",
        name => "Trial",
        price => 0,
        bandwidth => 1,
        start_date => "2018-07-20",
        end_date => "2018-07-27",
        package_is_active => 1
     },
     "asd@asd.asd" =>  {
        customer_id => 16648,
        customer_login_name => "******",
        customer_login_pwd => "********",
        customer_active => 1,
        customer_register_date => "2018-08-08 17:24:16",
        customer_dashboard_email => "******@*******.com",
        customer_dashboard_pwd => "******",
        used => "0.00",
        name => "Trial",
        price => 0,
        bandwidth => 1,
        start_date => "2018-08-08",
        end_date => "2018-08-15",
        package_is_active => 1
     },
     "mario@test.test" =>  {
        customer_id => 15271,
        customer_name => "MarioRossiTEST",
        customer_login_pwd => "*****",
        customer_active => 0,
        customer_register_date => "2018-06-22 11:36:42",
        customer_dashboard_email => "*****@******.com",
        customer_dashboard_pwd => "*******",
        used => "0.00",
        name => "Trial",
        price => 0,
        bandwidth => 1,
        start_date => "2018-06-22",
        end_date => "2018-06-30",
        package_is_active => 0
     },
  }
```

This way you can quickly access any "customer_id" by going $customers_dic["some@customer.name"]["customer_id"].

If you are just doing this a small number of times, you can just for loop through the customers array, keeping track of the index and checking if you have arrived on the desired customer's name.

```
$desired_customer_id;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($customers); $i++) {
    if ($customers[$i]["customer_name"] === $desired_customer_name) {
        $desired_customer_id = $customers[$i]["customer_id"];
    }
}
```

You could also do this with a foreach instead; choice is up to you. :)

Comment: `foreach` would be cleaner and less code. BTW, you have not decoded the JSON.

Comment: over looked that part at first and just added edit :)

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
```

then you need to find your customer

```
array_filter($arr['result']['customers'], function ($customer) {
    return ($customer['customer_name'] === 'test@test.test')
});
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: You should explain what `true` does as the second parameter and a link to the documentation would go far.